# Regression error term using Stata

Tags: regression, stata, error

When using Stata for multiple regression, where do I find the error term?

For the regression equation:
y = constant + B1*X1 + B2*X2 + ... + Bk*Xk + E

Where is E in the output from Stata?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike the coefficients and like the covariates, each observation has its own residual, so it would be hard for Stata to show you all of them in the output.

However, you can get Stata to predict them for you like this:

```
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. reg price mpg weight i.foreign 

      Source |       SS           df       MS      Number of obs   =        74
-------------+----------------------------------   F(3, 70)        =     23.29
       Model |   317252881         3   105750960   Prob > F        =    0.0000
    Residual |   317812515        70  4540178.78   R-squared       =    0.4996
-------------+----------------------------------   Adj R-squared   =    0.4781
       Total |   635065396        73  8699525.97   Root MSE        =    2130.8

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       price |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
         mpg |    21.8536   74.22114     0.29   0.769    -126.1758     169.883
      weight |   3.464706    .630749     5.49   0.000     2.206717    4.722695
             |
     foreign |
    Foreign  |    3673.06   683.9783     5.37   0.000     2308.909    5037.212
       _cons |  -5853.696   3376.987    -1.73   0.087    -12588.88    881.4934
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. predict ehat, residuals

. predict yhat, xb

. list price mpg weight foreign yhat ehat in 1/5, clean noobs 

    price   mpg   weight    foreign       yhat        ehat  
    4,099    22    2,930   Domestic   4778.672   -679.6717  
    4,749    17    3,350   Domestic    6124.58    -1375.58  
    3,799    22    2,640   Domestic   3773.907    25.09298  
    4,816    20    3,250   Domestic    5843.67    -1027.67  
    7,827    15    4,080   Domestic   8610.108   -783.1082
```

Comment: In addition, the output does include some summary information on the residuals: The standard deviation of the residuals is displayed as `Root MSE` in the upper right hand block. (The mean is by construction 0, so there is no need to report that)